# Program is not appending input taken from user to a text file?

Tags: arrays, c, string, file-io

Goal was to have a few default text samples written to a new text file, and then take more string inputs from user and append them to same file. But problem occurs in the **write_input()** function where it doesn't end the loop when *enter* is pressed nor does it append user input to text file. Maybe a normal *char array* should've been used as it would maybe been easier with inputs and testing? As of right now still practicing with double pointers and memory usage.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define max_rows 50
#define string_lenght 255

void input_starting_text(FILE *, char **);
void write_input(FILE *);
void free_mem(char **);

int main(void) {
    char *starting_text[] = { "First example of text.",
                                   "Second example of text.",
                                   "Third example of text." };
    const char *location = "textFile.txt";
    FILE *file;
    if ( (file = fopen(location, "w")) == NULL ) return 1;
    input_starting_text(file, starting_text);
    fclose(file);
    if ( (file = fopen(location, "a")) == NULL ) return 1;
    write_input(file);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}

void input_starting_text(FILE *file, char **text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (i == 2)
        {
            fprintf(file, "%s", text[i]);
        }
        else fprintf(file, "%s\n", text[i]);
    }
}

void write_input(FILE *file) {
    char **input = malloc(max_rows * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < max_rows; i++)
    {
        input[i] = malloc(max_rows * sizeof(char));
    }
    int n = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter text for writing to file: ");
        fgets(input[n], string_lenght, stdin);
        fprintf(file, "%s\n", input[n]);
        fflush(stdin);
        n++;
    } while (input[n] != "\n");
    free_mem(input);
}

void free_mem(char **text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < max_rows; i++)
    {
        free(text[i]);
    }
    free(text);
}
```

Comment: Review `max_rows` in `input[i] = malloc(max_rows * sizeof(char));`.  `string_lenght + 1` makes more sense.

Comment: Who or what text suggested using `fflush(stdin);`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i just used fflush because in some previous programs the input was always getting messed up so I looked up and came up with this solution. But when I think about it, that was only a problem when there was a previous scanf() function used in program, so I guess it doesn't belong here. On the other hand when using fflush(file) it writes to a text file as planned.

Comment: You can't compare a string with `==` or with `!=` like in `while (input[n] != "\n")`. Use `strcmp()`.

Comment: @57_Pixels "so I looked up and came up with this solution" --> recall where you looked up that _solution_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are flushing your `stdin` instead of your pointer to the file.
Try replacing your function :

```
void write_input(FILE *file) {
    char **input = malloc(max_rows * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < max_rows; i++)
    {
        input[i] = malloc(max_rows * sizeof(char));
    }
    int n = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter text for writing to file: ");
        fgets(input[n], string_lenght, stdin);
        fprintf(file, "%s\n", input[n]);
        fflush(file);
        n++;
    } while (input[n] != "\n");
    free_mem(input);
```

You can see that now contains `fflush(file);` instead of `stdin`.

Comment: When replacing with your suggestion, now the input is being written to a file so that solves that problem. Still the loop is not ending when enter is being pressed. Thank you

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is *undefined behaviour* because `stdin` is an input stream.

Comment: 1) `(max_rows` in `input[i] = malloc(max_rows * sizeof(char));` is too little for `fgets(input[n], string_lenght, stdin);`.  2) `while (input[n] != "\n");` is always true in C.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
Changed the program up a bit, removing *do while* loop and tested for first charachter in a *string for new line*, now everything works as expected.

```
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter text for writing to file: ");
        fgets(input[n], string_lenght, stdin);
        if (input[n][0] == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }
        fprintf(file, "%s", input[n]);
        fflush(file);
        n++;
    }
```

Comment: Note: `string_lenght` is the wrong value for an allocation of `input[i] = malloc(max_rows * sizeof(char))`.  Better code would also test the return value of `fgets()` against `NULL`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Could you please clarify why string_lenght is incorrect in this code?

Comment: 1) recall where you looked up [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71846155/program-is-not-appending-input-taken-from-user-to-a-text-file/71846843?noredirect=1#comment126961355_71846155) solution? 2) Code allocates 50 bytes for `input[n]`, yet tells `fgets()` there are 255 bytes in which to write.  Writing outside 50 bytes leads to _undefined behavior_.  If this is insufficient, perhaps clarify why you think `string_lenght` is correct?

Comment: I didn't think string_lenght is correct, just assumed it was appropriate for the code. Thanks for help.